# Proof of no-cloning

Tags: quantum-state, linear-algebra, no-cloning-theorem

I was reading a proof of No-cloning theorem, there are a couple of steps that are not clear to me, but the book does not give explanation for them. So here it is:
Theorem: It is impossible to create an identical copy of an arbitrary unknown quantum state.
Proof (by contradiction): Suppose that there exists a unitary $C$ (that copies an arbitrary unknown q-state). Then: [image].

This is the first thing I have trouble with, why do we take only one state ($\left| 0 \right>$ state) to prove that it is impossible to copy any arbitrary state into $any$ qubit?
The proof goes on stating:
[image]

Here I don't understand how (116) is the same as (117) (don't mind explaining the identity matrix in the middle). I will appreciate it if you make these 2 steps clearer to me.

Comment: Hi, Archil. Please use [MathJax](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/50/26) to write mathematical expressions. Images are not text-searchable (c.f. https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10573/199113).

Comment: I also give an intuitive proof of the no-cloning theorem in [this](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/4221/4153) answer.

Comment: Kindly mention the source from where you read this no cloning theorem? I am also interested

Comment: @A B, I probably read it on Vazirani's course on EdX, couldn't find it exactly but here is something very similar https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs191/fa05/lectures/lecture6_fa05.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For step (116), the equivalence between both of them is proved by

\begin{equation}
(\langle\psi_1|\otimes\langle0|)C^\dagger C(|\psi_2\rangle\otimes|0\rangle) = (\langle\psi_1|\otimes\langle0|)(|\psi_2\rangle\otimes|0\rangle) = \langle\psi_1|\psi_2\rangle\otimes\langle0|0\rangle=\langle\psi_1|\psi_2\rangle\langle0|0\rangle,
\end{equation}
where in the second step I used the property of tensor products that $(A\otimes B)(C\otimes D)=AC\otimes BD$, where obviously the dimensions of the multiplying matrices should match; and for the third step I used the fact that $\langle\psi_1|\psi_2\rangle$ and $\langle0|0\rangle$ are scalars, implying that their tensor product is just a multiplication between them.

For your first question, state $|0\rangle$ is used because it is the typical ancillary system used for quantum algorithms, that is, the zero state is the one used a auxilliary variable for doing the corresponding operations. However, note that the proof is not state dependent, meaning that you can take an arbitrary ancillary qubit, name it $|\rho\rangle$, and prove the theorem. Here I leave you such proof:
\begin{equation}
C(|\psi_1\rangle\otimes|\rho\rangle) = |\psi_1\rangle\otimes|\psi_1\rangle\\
C(|\psi_2\rangle\otimes|\rho\rangle) = |\psi_2\rangle\otimes|\psi_2\rangle
\end{equation}
And so $C$ would be the unitary we are looking for, so now the proof:
\begin{equation}
\langle\psi_1|\psi_2\rangle=\langle\psi_1|\psi_2\rangle\langle\rho|\rho\rangle =(\langle\psi_1|\otimes\langle\rho|)C^\dagger C(|\psi_2\rangle\otimes|\rho\rangle) = (\langle\psi_1|\otimes\langle\psi_1|)(|\psi_2\rangle\otimes|\psi_2\rangle)=(\langle\psi_1|\psi_2\rangle)^2.
\end{equation}
And so the same contradiction as before is obtained, and the theorem is proved.